# Python 2.7 converting list of strings to dictionary

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am trying to transform a list of the type

```
list = ['a=1','b=2','c=3','d=4']
```

to a dictionary of the type

```
dictionary = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'4'}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There are many ways. What have you tried? This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: `dict(s.split('=') for s in yourlist)`..

Comment: For future reference, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That suppose to work for you:

```
items = ['a=1','b=2','c=3','d=4']
d = {}
for item in items:
    a, b  = item.split('=')
    d.update({a:b})
print d # {'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2', 'd': '4'}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I did not do the downvote, but that vote was probably because you answered a question that deserved no answer. The comments under the question show that it should not be answered. The same kind of downvote has happened to me, but I have learned my lesson.